# Downloading a file from a URL using a cookie

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cookies

I am attempting to download a file from a web server e.g.

```
http://web.server.com/getfile=2
```

Now in the web browser I can do this, since I have authenticated myself and can view the cookie allowing to access the file.

I have done a fair bit of research and believe a cookie container would hold the cookie, although I am unable to determine how then you can download this file from within C# using the CookieContainer

Comment: make a get request to the page containg cookie, store the cookie and attach to second request to getfile

Comment: Thank you, thats just the simple logic i needed! Thanks :)

Comment: Good luck and mark it answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a HTTP get request to the page containg cookie, store the cookie and attach to second request to getfile.

ToDo: Add a sample

Answer (score 4):

In c# you should use a WebClient.
Although it can be used independently, code like this will reduce your headache of adding a cookie header everytime.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```